# How can I restrict to 1 row edit?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I'm using ng2-smart-table and currently having problems with its edit mode. It is supporting multiple rows editing, but I only want it to edit 1 row only, and the other rows are disabled until I exit edit mode of that row.

This is quite an obvious problem but I could not find answers anywhere. How can I achieve this function in my table?

Below is the settings for my table:

```
settings = {
    hideSubHeader: true,
    actions: {
      columnTitle: 'Edit/Delete',
      add: false,
      position: 'right'
    },
    edit: {
      confirmSave: true,
      confirmEdit: true,
      editButtonContent: '<img src="../../../assets/images/pencil.png" width="20" height="20">'
    },
    delete: {
      confirmDelete: true,
      deleteButtonContent: '<img src="../../../assets/images/delete.png" width="20" height="20">'
    },
    columns: {
      index: {
        title: 'No',
        filter: false,
        editable: false,
        valuePrepareFunction(value, row, cell) { return cell.row.index + 1; }
      },
      categoryname: {
        title: 'Category name',
        filter: false
      },
      color: {
        title: 'Color',
        filter: false,
        type: 'custom',
        renderComponent: ColorLabelComponent,
        editor: {
          type: 'custom',
          component: ColorGetterComponent
        }
      },
      note: {
        title: 'Note',
        filter: false
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post your code whatever you tried. Without showing your code we are not able to guide you in right direction.

Comment: I have updated with the "settings" variable for my table.